# How to find TypeError when position is not specified?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm testing out some pieces of code I've found but I'm having trouble identifying the error.

The code:

```py
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import time
import math
import scipy.optimize as optimize


start = dt.datetime(2016,12,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,12,1)


tick = ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'AMZN']


#pandas dataframe
data = web.DataReader(tick, 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
data = np.log(data/data.shift(1))


def sharpetest(wts, returns):
  weights = np.array(wts)
  port_return = np.sum(returns.mean() * weights) * 252
  port_vol = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(returns.cov() * 252, weights)))
  sharpe = port_return/port_vol
  sharpe = np.array(sharpe)
  return sharpe
  

num_assets = len(tick)

constraints = ({'type' : 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) -1})
bounds = tuple((0,1) for x in range(num_assets))
args = (num_assets * [1./num_assets,], data)


optimal_sharpe=optimize.minimize(sharpetest,
                               args,
                               method = 'SLSQP',
                               bounds = bounds,
                               constraints = constraints)
print(optimal_sharpe)
```

Output:

```
   /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:83:
   VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list- 
   or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If 
   you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
   return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

As you can see, the line where the TypeError is not specified. How do I find the error?

I apologize for asking such a rudimentary question.

Comment: Many of the problems with these `optimize` functions comes from not paying enough attention to the documentation.  The `minimize` arguments are supposed to be in the form: `(fun, x0, args=(), method=None,...)`.

Comment: Errors provide tracebacks, but warnings don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type error was coming from the application of the function `sharpetest`.  It comes from combining the weight with the data.  Here is an example of how to correct the code.

```
constraints = ({'type' : 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) -1})
bounds = tuple((0,1) for x in range(num_assets))
x0 = num_assets * [1./num_assets,]
args =  (data)

print(sharpetest(num_assets * [1./num_assets,], data))

optimal_sharpe=optimize.minimize(sharpetest,
                               x0,
                               args,
                               method = 'SLSQP',
                               bounds = bounds,
                               constraints = constraints)
print(optimal_sharpe)
```

You can see that `x0` is broken out to its own argument and then the additional data (the returns of the stocks) are passed in as the args. A very interesting example you have!

The output I get is

```
     fun: array(0.79108107)
     jac: array([-7.45058060e-09,  7.86704488e-01,  7.25132324e-01])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 12
     nit: 3
    njev: 3
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1.00000000e+00, 1.38777878e-16, 0.00000000e+00])
```

Comment: should it be `args=(data,)`, a tuple?

Comment: Yes it should be a tuple just of one value in your case.  (data) is a tuple, so it (), so is (data, None), so is (data, None, None, "a") etc.  Have a look at this for the definition of a tuple https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple.

Comment: `(data)` is not a tuple, unless `data` itself is a tuple.  SIngle element tuples require the comma.